# Angular Material nested table not displaying nested json data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I'm having a weird issue trying to display nested JSON data within a MatTable using Angular Material.
I'm displaying the data using an observable datasource and looping through that using matCellDef - all standard stuff.

```html
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of tableColumns">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
            
      etc....
      
    </ng-container>

    
    <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item" [attr.colspan]="nestedColumns.length">
            <div class="example-element-detail" *ngIf="item.nestedData?.length" [@detailExpand]="item == expandedElement ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
                <div class="inner-table mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="expandedElement">
          <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
                  <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}" *ngFor="let column of nestedColumns">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>

                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let item">
                    
          <pre>{{item.nestedData | json}}</pre>   <!----This displays the object data-->
          
          <pre>{{item.nestedData[column] | json}}</pre>   <!----This displays nothing -->
          
          
                </td>

            </ng-container>




            <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="nestedColumns"></tr>
            <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: nestedColumns;"></tr>
          </table>
```

**JSON data**

```json
{
  "ID": 0,
  "description": "seed data",
  "type": 1,
  "level": 1,
  "item": false,
  "colour": false,
  "display": false,
  "methodology": false,
  "nestedData": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "description": "more seed",
      "used": 3,
      "taken": 4,
      "available": 0,
      "broken": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

I can display the top level JSON data perfectly in the outer table, however when I attempt to display the nested JSON data in the inner table, it doesn't display anything.
However, when I emit preformatted text via json, I can see the object just fine.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the JSON as well ?

Comment: Sure, just added to question.

Comment: so the `nestedData` can have an array of JSON objects? Also `nestedColumns` which you are using in `item.nestedData[column]` are the keys right ?

Comment: Just for test purposes try `item.nestedData[0][column]` does it work?

Comment: Correct, nestedData has an array of nested JSON objects. Yep, the keys are right, one of the first things I checked by rendering a preformatted list of the keys in the browser to see if they matched correctly with the object keys

Comment: "Just for test purposes try item.nestedData[0][column]" --> gimme 1 sec, gonna try that now

Comment: Dayummm. Thank you sir! Nice one. I had gotten so focused on getting nestedData to display, I forgot it actually contained an array of objects!!

Comment: No problem, this happens :D